# How to organize .ipynb and .py files into subfolders and allow imports?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a repository to organize data, script files (py), and notebook files (ipynb). So the top level folder structure could look like this

```
project
- data
- notebooks
- src
```

Since I have many notebooks, I would like to organize them further into subfolders; similar for `src` and `data`.

From what I understand, by default, a notebook thinks the root folder is the folder it's in. Thus it can only import anything located in that folder; it can't see `data`, `src`, or any of their subfolders. What is the best practice to address this?

My current idea is to use an environment variable that holds the path to `project` and set this value as the root path in each notebook. For example, let's say the path is `/home/alice/project` which is stored in the environment variable `MY_PROJECT_PATH`. Then, in a notebook, I can do something like

```
import os
PATH = os.getenv('MY_PROJECT_PATH')
os.chdir(PATH)

from src.dummy import *
```

While this works just fine, I wonder if there are any downsides to this – apart from adding this code snippet to each notebook and ensuring the environment variable is indeed visible – or if there is a better or more convenient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer for this could be that, maybe if you don't want to have to set that environment variable every time, and the path to your `src` isn't going to change.

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))
```

With the caveat that each subfolder deeper into `notebooks` you go you'll need more `, '..'` i.e.

```py
import sys, os
# From project/notebooks to project
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))
# From project/notebooks/abc to project
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', '..'))
```

There's a lot of robust answers for all the ways to handle relative imports across a lot of other questions, some that go into great detail on the mechanics of module loading or get opinionated about whether you should change the path or not.

Comment: thanks! Yes, I thought about relative inputs. But as you said, for deeper hierarchies it gets a bit "ugly". But more importantly, it would make re-organizing the notebooks later on more difficult. Maybe I want/need to move a notebooks somewhere else in the hierarchy incl. at a different depth. Then I would need to check and fix the code every time. A solution using an absolute parent path seems more maintenance friendly.

Comment: Only if you're only planning on using them on that machine, or can expect everyone to remember to set `MY_PROJECT_PATH`, but it is a pick your poison.